# Make 2 numbers reach their target numbers at the same time

Tags: c, math, axis

I'm trying to code a mouse drag function in C. Basically, i want X to reach targetX, and Y to reach targetY at the same time. For example:

```
x = 0, y = 0;
targetX = 10, targetY = 20;
```

I want to make `x` reach `targetX` by the time `y` reaches `targetY`. I want it to loop until both `x` and `y` reach their target number, incrementing them by 1 each time to actually achieve that. So, at one point, `x` would be 9, and `y` would be 19, then it would increment them each by 1, causing them to both equal their target numbers, instead of `x` reaching `targetX` first, then `y` getting incremented solo (which is what my current code does). Also, i need it to be able to decrement (instead of increment) `x` or `y` (or both), as well.

Here is what i have now:

```
for (x; x < targetX || x > targetX;) {
    x = (x < targetX) ? x + 1 : x - 1;
    y = (y < targetY) ? y + 1 : y - 1;
    mouse_move(x, y);
}
for (y; y < targetY || y > targetY;) {
    y = (y < targetY) ? y + 1 : y - 1;
    mouse_move(x, y);
}
```

It doesn't have to be in C, i'm just looking for a way to make `x` and `y` reach their target numbers at the same time.

Comment: This question boils down to following a straight line between two points. Here's [a question on drawing that line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35970872/1270789), which should help.

Comment: Note: `for (x; x < targetX || x > targetX;)` is equivalent to `while (x != targetX)`.

Comment: Similarly, `x = (x < targetX) ? x + 1 : x - 1;` could be written as: `x += x < targetX ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Essentially compute the slope between initial and target and use the slope values for your loop deltas.

Comment: See [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save the initial x.
2. Save the initial y.
3. delta x = target x - initial x
4. delta y = target y - initial y
5. num steps = max of the deltas (or whatever you want)
6. For step = 1 .. num steps,

   1. fraction = step / num steps
   2. x = initial x + ( fraction * delta x )
   3. y = initial y + ( fraction * delta y )
   4. Move the mouse